# Calculate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_1^e x^m e^x (\log x)^n dx$ with limsup and liminf

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I have a question about how to prove the limit using $\limsup$.
On the other day, I was asked the following problem in the exam:

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers.
> Calculate the following limit, where $m$ is fixed.
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_1^e x^m e^x (\log x)^n dx
> $$

To this problem, I answered in the manner shown below:

(My solution) Take any $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$.
Now $f_n(x)$ denotes the integrand of the integral in question ($f_n(x)$ depends on $m$ of course, but $m$ is fixed in this problem so no problems may occur even if $m$ is not appear in the notation).
First, split the integral into two pieces,
$$
\int_1^e f_n(x) dx
= \int_1^{e - \varepsilon} f_n(x) dx
+ \int_{e - \varepsilon}^e f_n(x) dx,
$$
and call the first term $I_1$ and the second $I_2$.
Since all of $x^m$, $e^x$ and $(\log x)^n$ are increasing functions on $[1, e]$, so is $f_n(x)$.
Then, $I_1$ is evaluated as below:
$$
I_1
\le \int_1^{e - \varepsilon} f_n(e - \varepsilon) dx
= f_n(e - \varepsilon)(e - \varepsilon - 1).
$$
Similarly, $I_2$ is evaluated like
$$
I_2
\le \int_{e - \varepsilon}^e f_n(e)
= f_n(e)\varepsilon.
$$
Since $\log(e - \varepsilon) \in (0, 1)$, I obtained
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(e - \varepsilon)(e - \varepsilon - 1)
= \lim_{n \to \infty} (e - \varepsilon)^m e^{e - \varepsilon} (\log(e - \varepsilon))^n
= 0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(e)\varepsilon
= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^m e^e (\log e)^n \varepsilon
= e^{m + e}\varepsilon.
$$
Therefore, I conclude that
$$
0 \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_1^e f_n(x) dx
\le \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_1^e f_n(x)
\le \limsup_{n \to \infty} (I_1 + I_2)
\le \limsup_{n \to \infty} (f_n(e - \varepsilon)(e - \varepsilon - 1) + f_n(e)\varepsilon)
= e^{m + e}\varepsilon.
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, both $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of the integral as $n \to \infty$ must be $0$, which indicates
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_1^e x^m e^x (\log x)^n dx = 0.
$$

Is my proof valid or invalid? If there are either trivial or nontrivial mistakes, please let me know which part I should modify.
Especially, my most worried thing is how to use $\liminf$ and $\limsup$.

Comment: Very nice proof. There is a (trivial) mistake after "I obtained..." where you omit the factor of $(e - \varepsilon -1)$ in the RHS of the first equality. There is no real need for $\limsup$ because, as you may note, the terms are decreasing in $n$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! I've rewritten your title. Ideally users should have some idea about the content of a question without needing to open the question itself. This makes it easier for potential answerers to recognize the content of the question, and it makes it easier for people with similar questions to recognize whether this question might help them. I've also used the [tag:solution-verification] tag to indicate that this question is about checking a proposed solution. This (and the [tag:proof-verification]) are important tags, as the questions are rather different. Happy mathing!

Comment: @legionwhale Thanks for your fine check. I'm relieved to see the ignorance of that factor does not have critical influences because that factor is multiplied by $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is valid, and very well-written.

Eventually you will learn about Measure Theory and [Dominated Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), and then this one is a one-liner!

Comment: I'm very thankful to your fast reply! I will be able to use $\limsup$ with ample courage. If there is enough free time, I'm going to try to study Lebesgue integral theory.

Comment: @kuHamrry As you are relatively new to the site, I wanted to add that you can click the green checkmark "accept" to indicate that an answer has resolved your question. (In fact, I've seen that you've already done so). And you should *also* probably upvote any answer you find helpful. Here, it would probably be a good idea to upvote an answer that you accept.